# multiple Output windows in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

Is there a way to have more than one Output window open in Visual Studio at the same time?

Comment: Three years later, and I'm looking for this same option. I want Source Control output open as well as build output....

Comment: Same here. I'm using VS 2013, though.

I'm want to have two output windows, one showing the build, and one showing Tests - which I'm using for test automation.

Every time I run a test, the output window shows the output for 'Build', I have to set it to 'Tests' to follow the output. It's cumbersome.

Comment: 5 years later, I'm using VS2015 and looking for same option!

Comment: Near 10 years later, Visual Studio 2022 is on the door, and we don't have this option yet...

Answer (score 3):

**It is not possible** with the built-in Visual Studio settings.

The only workaround would be to develop VS extension which adds an additional custom Output Window maybe.